# manual numbering

Tags: numbering

I'm writing some exercises with latex. They come from different references and I would like to set manually the number of the exercise every time, in order to keep the enumeration from the respective reference. 
Must be a very simple task, but still I can't figure it out.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please elaborate. Examples and your codes so far will be helpful. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Check out the `enumitem` package. But as @Masroor says, you should provide a minimal working example (even if it has the wrong numbers). It's hard to provide a good answer without knowing exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like maybe you could use the description environment if you want to explicitly set each number with a custom format.

```
\begin{description}
\item [A.] first example
\item [3.] second example
\end{description}
```